# Join 2d list of characters into a string

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Suppose loc is a 2d list of characters, I want to join it into a string s. Which of the following code is faster, in general?

```
s = ''.join([''.join(row) for row in loc])

s = ''.join([x for row in loc for x in row])
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think `''.join(chain.from_iterable(loc))` will beat both.

Comment: Probably, the first because there is only one iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module to see the time difference.

```
import timeit

loc = [('a', 'b'),('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]

s1 = lambda: ''.join([''.join(row) for row in loc])    
s2 = lambda: ''.join([x for row in loc for x in row])

print 'Time required by s1:', timeit.timeit(s1)
print 'Time required by s2:', timeit.timeit(s2)
```

Gives the time required result as:

```
Time required by s1: 1.29390706928
Time required by s2: 1.46863953561
```

---

Explanation:

1) For **s1**:
`[''.join(row) for row in loc]` requires 3`(for row in loc)` * 2`(''.join(row))` = 6 iterations
       and we get `['ab', 'cd', 'ef']` as input for the outermost `join`    function which again requires 3 iterations.
So total number of iteration required by s1 is 6 + 3 = **9**.

2)For **s2**:
`[x for row in loc for x in row]` requires 3`(for row in loc)` * 2`(for x in row)` = 6 iterations
       and we get `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` as input for the outermost `join`    function which requires 6 iterations.
So total number of iteration required by s2 is 6 + 6 = **12**.

So as a result **s1** takes less time than **s2**.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the timing results from the two approaches you mentioned as well as using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
loc = np.random.randint(97, 123, (100, 100)).view('U2').tolist()

timeit.timeit("''.join([''.join(row) for row in loc])", setup="from __main__ import loc", number=10000)
1.1168044869991718

timeit.timeit("''.join([x for row in loc for x in row])", setup="from __main__ import loc", number=10000)
4.264987408001616

timeit.timeit("''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(loc))", setup="from __main__ import loc", number=10000)
2.068879542996001
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and adding the results using intertools.chain.from_iterable. I cannot accept more than one useful answers, though.